# Some Numbers in Arial Font too short?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I noticed in my WPF Application that some numbers are a little bit shorter than others.
I used the Arial Font.
The Numbers are 1,2,4 and 7.
[image]
Is there a possibility to get every number to the same level?

Comment: This is an intended behaviour of the font, because the rounded bottoms of e.g. 3 seem to be slightly higher than the flat bottoms of e.g. 1. Therefore, they need a visual correction (moving them slightly downwards).

Comment: @Nico, you should make this an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Fonts are visual elements. Therefore, they don't have to be mathematically exact but they have to look good. One thing that helps fonts looking good is a consistent visual base line.

A rounded edge of a character appears to be slightly shorter than a flat edge, even if the bounding box is the same. That's why rounded edged at the bottom line are usually extended slightly to give the appearance of a consistent base line.

The top edges are probably not that important for the readability and look of a font. I assume, that's why the top edges are not extended similarly.

Comment: And the answer to the question is?

Comment: I understand that argument if you use Numbers with a small FontSize. My Problem is that i want to display big Numbers on a 27 Inch display.

Comment: @Bulli It should work even with big numbers. Of course, you should not display a ruler underneath. Or is the height difference that obvious?

Comment: This is the intended Size i want to see in my applicatiion. The Height different is even without the rulers too obviously :-/